# Most efficient way to check for existence of multiple items

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database

Does anybody know what the most efficient way is to *check for the existence of multiple items (up to 1000) in a large db table* (1,000,000 rows+) to see if they need to be added, using EF / Linq / a Sql Server db (hosted on Azure)?

At the moment I'm been getting very slow performance (although when I was initially developing on a local Sql db it was much better) using both of the following methods.

Should I need to consider leaving EF for this task, and running some SQL directly against the db?

```
//loop to check all imported items against db
private void ImportNewSerialsWorkerUsingLoopCheck(List<foo> importedFoos)
{
    List<foos> foosToAddToDb = new List<foo>();
    foreach (var foo in importedFoos)
    {
        fooCheck = context.Foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Serial == foo.Serial);
        if (fooCheck == null)
        {
            foosToAddToDb.Add(foo);
        }
    }
    context.foos.AddRange(foosToAddToDb);
}


//use Any() to check all imported items against db
private void ImportNewSerialsWorkerUsingAnyCheck(List<foo> importedFoos)
{
    var foosToAddToDb = importedFoos.Where(i => !context.foos.Any(f => f.Serial == i.Serial)).ToList();    
    context.foos.AddRange(foosToAddToDb);
}
```

**Update**

I've just run a sql profiler trace against a local sql db while using the `.Any()` LINQ command in `var foosToAddToDb = importedFoos.Where(i => !context.foos.Any(f => f.Serial == i.Serial)).ToList();` command, and discovered that EF runs it as individual sql queries for each item in `importedFoos`, so there definitely doesn't seem to be any advantage in using that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second snippet is performing an EF query as a part of a Linq to objects query, hence why it performs a query for each item.  You need to perform just one EF query to do one round trip to the db.

```
var serials = importedFoos. Select(foo => too.Serial);
var existing = context.Foos.Where(foo  => serials.Contains(foo.Serial));
var toAdd = importedFoos.Except(existing);
```

Comment: Ah thanks Servy, will give this a go asap, I've fallen foul of doing unnecessary .ToList() calls in the past.

Comment: @Ted if `importedFoos` is actually an EF query that you unnecessarily materialized then this is much easier.  Just don't materialize it and write `context.Foos.Except(importedFoos);` and you're done, and with the most efficient implemention as well.